# Can I install Ubuntu on a computer that has no operating system?

Tags: installation

I have an old laptop that has had System32 deleted. Is it possible to install ubuntu, and if so HOW?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  If you can get hold of an Ubuntu DVD or USB stick then it's easy just follow the link given by Mitch.  If you have access to another computer that has Windows or Linux you can [download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and create a DVD or USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on given RAM - you could try it first with Lubuntu (32-Bit-CD) - but if RAM is smaller than about 120 MB to 130 MB - then it would not work with Ubuntu (32-Bit-CD). Would be good if you deliver a hardware - description too. Because e.g. intel centrino is not easily (I did not achieve with centrino and Ubuntu up to today) to be installed with Lubuntu resp. Ubuntu. ( It depends too - if CD-drive is able to boot properly in case it is a really old Laptop ... )

Comment: I don't have PAE on my CPU. I'm curently reverting to the "mini.iso", with the disc setup. This doesn't have PAE, but looks ugly. Any others not have PAE that I could use?

Comment: @Bman This PAE thingie ... with elder hardware - you could try then 32-bit-iso of Debian7 - only in case, if no Ubuntu-derivative is working. only dont know, if you need then add boot-option at Debian7 (with pressing 'TAB' - key at start of booting) - then below in line you add: edd=off (not sure if this is necessary with yours, but at intel centrino it is necessary). - you still did not give any hardware info...